# php require in class file

Tags: php, require

I have the following folder structure for my site:

```
    Admin/
    Tech/
index.php
    classes/
    include/
    core/
```

Everything seems to work except for when i try to call the following code from Admin/index.php

```
<?php
#including our init.php
require '../core/init.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();
?>
```

I get the following error for some reason. I can't figure out what to do to fix it or if its even possible to fix.

The core/init.php file has the following code:

```
<?php
    #starting the users session
    session_start();
    require 'include/database.php';
    require 'classes/users.php';
    require 'classes/general.php';

    $users = new Users($db);
    $general = new General();

    $errors = array();
?>
```

error that i am receiving:

```
PHP Warning:  require(include/database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: could you please add some indent or space to make your folder structure more readable?

Comment: ok i added some indent space, hopefully that helps.

Comment: These all directories are at the same level?

Comment: yes they are all at the same level

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need:

```
require '../include/database.php';
require '../classes/users.php';
require '../classes/general.php';
```

But if you use a lot of relative paths, it can get messy real quickly so you might want to consider using your base-directory like for example (you can also use a variable or a constant for that):

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/database.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/users.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/general.php';
```

Comment: I tried what you said which works perfect, but i ran into a weird issue though, i have the following section:  if($_SESSION['role'] == "Admin"){
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/index.php');
   }else{
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tech/index.php');
   }                                                                    but for some reason when it tries to redirect instead of going to http://document_root/admin/index.php it goes to http://document_root/admin/admin/index.php

Comment: @BradHazelnut No, in your `header()` call you need to use the path relative to the web-root, not the file-system. So there it is just `'/tech/index.php'`, possibly with the domain name in front of it.

Comment: I changed the code to just be tech/index.php and it still does that not sure why its doing that, any ideas?

Comment: @BradHazelnut You need an absolute path like `/tech/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use paths relative to current script location, like this:

```
<?php

require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../core/other.inc');

...
?>
```

You always have it under control, regardless of the `include_path` PHP ini setting.

In your case you should have the following:

```
<?php
  #including our init.php
  require(dirname(__FILE__).'/core/init.php');
  $general->logged_in_protect();
?>
```

and `core/init.php` will look like:

```
<?php
    #starting the users session
    session_start();
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../include/database.php');
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../classes/users.php');
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../classes/general.php');

    $users = new Users($db);
    $general = new General();

    $errors = array();
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: awesome, that sounds like exactly what i need. would you be able to give me an example on how i can use it with the my code please?